# jQuery Ajax submit form returns error with some character combinations

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery.ajax function to post a form to  the server. The code works well except for when some input fields in the form contain some specific character combinations such as &# (&@ works fine).

Below the is the code we use to submit the form:

```
function formSubmit(formToPost, postUrl, onSuccess) {
        console.debug("formSubmit");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: postUrl,
            data: $('#' + formToPost).serialize(),
            success: onSuccess
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.debug("error: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown); });
    }
```

The error returned when I try to submit the form with &# in one of the input fields is "Internal Server Error" without anymore details.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the request makes it to the server?  If it does, have you debugged the server-side code to see where it fails?

Comment: An "Internal Server Error" is just that--an error on the server side. The error is there. What kind of code are you hitting?

Comment: The request doesn't make it way to the server at all. I put a breakpoint at the start of the method that corresponds to the postUrl passed but the breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I should have put the breakpoint in an earlier stage than the actual controller action I am calling using the postURL (I am using MVC 3). Sorry again for the wrong question and thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work . Which basically decodeURI after serialize of form data.

```
function formSubmit(formToPost, postUrl, onSuccess) {
        console.debug("formSubmit");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: postUrl,
            data: decodeURI($('#' + formToPost).serialize()),
            success: onSuccess
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.debug("error: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown); });
    }
```